# How to limit the columns returned with a nested relationship - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to limit the columns returned on an eloquent relationship with no luck.

The following works:

```
$books = Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

but what I need does not work:

```
$books = Book::with('author.company:id,name,phone')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You are eager loading specific columns.***

> When using this feature, you **should always** include the `id` column and
> any relevant `foreign key` columns in the list of columns you wish to
> retrieve.

So check you company table and make sure you add all foreign key columns,

For example: If this is my company table has a column called `owner_id`, `address_id`, you have to add it to the `with()` method like this.

```
$books = Book::with('author:id,name, owner_id, address_id')->get();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.   Thank you.   I could not find this in the documentation.

Comment: Glad it works.  The rule was just stated in the warning section … https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that.   Thanks again!